# Passing a proxy URL before using proxy pass in Nginx config

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I need to pass a proxy URL to connect to other URLs mentioned as proxy pass in Nginx.

Example: If I have to connect to google.com through a Linux server box, I have to set proxy as xyz.org:80 and only then I can connect to google.com.

So how can I achieve it in Nginx config?

My Nginx config file goes like this:

```
http {
include mime.types;
}
server{
   listen     80;
   server_name   *;
  return 301     https://$host$request_uri;
}

location /xyz{
   proxy_pass     google.com/
}
```

Here, I need to pass my proxy xyz.org:80 in the nginx config itself and only then I can connect to google.com/.

So basically, every request from my server box should pass via xyz.org:80 to the proxy_pass location.

Comment: That does not look like an `nginx` configuration file (and would not pass an `nginx -t` test). If this question is about using `nginx` as a *forward proxy*, then [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/604352/nginx-as-forward-proxy-for-https) may help.

Comment: This is just an example of the nginx file. I want to hit google.com via a proxy and i need to mention the proxy in nginx config itself but google.com is already mentioned as proxy_pass.